# Subdomain point to different websites in same IIS

Tags: iis, dns

I have an IIS server With a default Website running, an react app running in the the /LandingPage path and an API used by the React app in the /api, so basically I have:

localhost:80/ -> Default MVC website

localhost:80/LandingPage -> React APP

localhost:80/api -> API to be consumed by the APP.

Currently I have a domain pointing to the server, so I can access it externally, but I want to create a sub-domain to the APP/API so I don't need to see the /LandingPage in my URL's.

Am I able to set my sub-domain to point directly to my localhost:80/LandingPage? Should I do that on IIS or it's done in the DNS config?

Basically accessing "app.domain.com" would point directly to the "localhost:80/LandingPage", is that possible?

Thank you!

Comment: Create a new website in IIS and map it your react app and add your sub-domain `app.domain.com` binding to this website. In this way, you will be able to access your react app at your sub-domain url externally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is. You need to create a virtual server on IIS. I'm no expert on IIS, but it involves:

- Creating different folders for each website.
- [Creating two different Web Site on IIS Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/getting-started-with-iis/create-a-web-site) with the path to your web content folder.
- **Bind your hostname**. *Bindings* option will appear under *Actions* tab on the right side when you select your website connection under *Sites*.

  - Once you get to the bindings screen, click *Add*.
  - Enter your domain name in the *Host name* field.

---

More info:

- [Digicert's guide on how to configure host names with **screenshots**](https://www.digicert.com/ssl-support/ssl-host-headers-iis-8.htm).
- [Microsoft's Documentation on Add/Edit Site Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc771629(v=ws.11)).
- [How to properly set bindings in IIS server](https://serverfault.com/questions/445548/how-to-properly-set-bindings-in-iis-server).
- [Configure a Host Header for a Web Site (IIS 7)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc753195(v=ws.10))

Comment: I totally forgot about the hostnames, it worked great, thank you!