# configure two dydns websites of IIS with two different SSL ports and configure port forwarding for both

Tags: dynamic, dns, portforwarding

I have two iis websites. One I have a localhost on port 80 and was setup for dydns with ssl port forwarding external: 443 and internal port:1124 and the website is working perfectly with dydns access.

I wanted to setup another website with the ssl port but was unable to do so. As when I set the port forwarding external Ssl:443 and the internal ssl port:1129. the other dydns entry redirects to the first website. This website does not work without https.
So. How do I setup two websites for ssl port forwarding on the same machine?
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't necessary need an entirely different port for each website you host on the same machine. You can use the same http/80 and https/443 to serve multiple website through virtual hosts.

I'm not familiar with IIS, but I do know that it's possible on IIS just like Apache and NGINX does. You can read about setting up virtual hosts on IIS [here](https://support.simpledns.plus/kb/a116/virtual-hosting-with-iis-internet-information-services-iis-6_0-windows-xp-server-2003-and-earlier.aspx). Also I answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51414167/3209381).